# Which http status code for 'entity not found'?

Tags: rest, web-services, http, webserver

```
/persons?age=18
```

Imagine a search does not return any results (means: no entity found for the request).

If I'd return a `404` here, that would suggest that maybe the `/persons` path is invalid entirely.

Is there any accepted status code that could be return if the request was valid in general (means: the path exists, and the request parameters have been valid), but still there is no data to return?

`204` is not suitable either, as this is used to tell the user "your request was 200 OK, but there will never be a response body to your request" (like for modifications).

Comment: You can use HTTP 204 No Content. https://restfulapi.net/http-status-204-no-content/

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any accepted status code that could be return if the request was valid in general (means: the path exists, and the request parameters have been valid), but still there is no data to return?

[200](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) is appropriate when the resource has a representation, even if that representation is an empty list.

```
# Request:
GET /persons?age=18

# Response:
200 OK

[]
```

Think "web search page that returns no results", downloading an empty file.

[Jim Webber's 2011 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) may help with perspective here: the status codes and headers belong to the "transferring documents over a network" domain, not to your domain application protocol.  The components that are specific to your application should be paying attention to the messages in the body of the response; the meta data is directed at general purpose components that are transferring documents.

Comment: What if I'd like to transfer an error message or code additionally in the message body? Usually clients will expect a json response like `{ persons: [] }`. So I could not simply return exceptional content as body when using a 200 ok...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should return 200.
The number of entities found does not change the http code.